# How can I　add <g:textField> in ".innerHTML"?

Tags: javascript, grails, innerhtml, appendchild

I want to make 2 input type=radio.  when I click second radio button, I want to  add four button by tag "".   How can I　add input tag in ".innerHTML" ? 
Don't answer by JQuery cuz this system can't using jquery's append() method.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function appendChildDM()
{
  var so = document.createElement('span');
  so.innerHTML="<b> Name:  </b><g:textField name="name" value="${name}" required="true"　maxlength="30" ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML="<b> Company:  </b><g:textField name="company" value="${company}" maxlength="30" ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML="<b>E-mail:  </b><g:textField name="email" required="true" value="${email}"></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML="<b>Phone:  </b><g:textField name="phone" value="${phone}"></g:textField>";
 document.getElementById('apch').appendChild(so);
}
</script>
```

in "Body" tag

```
   <font size="2"><b>　　System Contact Information:  <input type="radio" name="sessionUserInfo" value="1"  checked="true"/></b>　　　 <b>Name:</b>　${t.memid_name}

  <g:hiddenField name="sessionName" value = "${t.memid_name}" id="subscribeField"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="sessionOrgName" value = "${t.contract_eorg}"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="sessionEmail" value = "${t.memid_email}"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="sessionPhone" value = "${t.memid_home}"/>
  <g:hiddenField name="memdataId" value = "${t.memdata_id}"/>
                    </font>
<br><br>
<div id='apch'>
<font size="2"><p><b>　Other Contact Information:　<input type="radio" name="sessionUserInfo"  value="2" onclick="appendChildDM();"/></b></p><br>

　</font>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you are using = instead of +=, using = will replace ur existing innerhtml.
Is the below what you expect?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function appendChildDM()
{
  var so = document.createElement('span');
  so.innerHTML+="<b> Name:  </b><g:textField name="name" value="${name}" required="true"　maxlength="30" ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML+="<b> Company:  </b><g:textField name="company" value="${company}" maxlength="30" ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML+="<b>E-mail:  </b><g:textField name="email" required="true" value="${email}"></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML+="<b>Phone:  </b><g:textField name="phone" value="${phone}"></g:textField>";
 document.getElementById('apch').appendChild(so);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        You can dynamically add en element to the DOM by two ways: by inserting an html code into the parent element or by creating a child element with some properties. In your example the two methods are mixed - therefore senseless.
Method 1. Inserting HTML code:

        var radio = '<input type ="radio" id="' + id + '" value="" />';
        ele.innerHTML = radio;
        document.getElementById(id).onclick = function(){ alert('this is test'); };
Method 2. Creating DOM child:

var radioButton = document.createElement('input');
radioButton.type = "radio";
radioButton.id = id;
radioButton.onclick = function(){ alert('this is test'); };
ele.appendChild(radioButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace `=` by `+=` and you have put double quotes everywhere which lead to errors.

```
function appendChildDM(){
  var so = document.createElement('span');

  so.innerHTML = /* because the span is empty */ "<b> Name:  </b><g:textField name='name' value='${name}' required='true'　maxlength='30' ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML += "<b> Company:  </b><g:textField name='company' value='${company}' maxlength='30' ></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML += "<b>E-mail:  </b><g:textField name='email' required='true' value='${email}'></g:textField><br><br>";
  so.innerHTML +="<b>Phone:  </b><g:textField name='phone' value='${phone}'></g:textField>";

  // and for the input radio
  so.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='theName' /> <input type='radio' name='theName' />";
  document.getElementById('apch').appendChild(so);
}
```